# Some Screens not running on emulator but running on a physical device

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I am building a App with flutter. The thing is that some screens give error when they are run on a android emulator while they function properly when run on a physical device. Why?

One thing I noticed, in my case, is that they always give this error: `Null Check Operator applied on a null value`.

For example, in one my screen, user uploads a file to the database but in the emulator, when I tried uploading it, the file variable in the code was appearing to be null. The process was like this: You see a upload button, clicking on it will redirect you to library where you will select the image/file to upload and immediately come back to the app where you can input you thoughts for that file and upload it.

Now, on emulator, when I came back to the screen, all I could see was the Red Screen Error... But when on a physical device, the screen was functioning properly.